# Are /var/mail/root and /var/spool/mail/root hardlinks for the same inode?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls, hardlink, inode

Just found out this:

```
# diff /var/mail/root /var/spool/mail/root
# (nothing)
# ls -i /var/mail/root /var/spool/mail/root
1284 /var/mail/root  1284 /var/spool/mail/root
```

Same content, same 1284 inode number, therefore they are two hardlinks for the same file, right?

But:

```
# ls -l /var/mail/root /var/spool/mail/root
-rw------- 1 root mail 63743972 Nov 14 16:40 /var/mail/root
-rw------- 1 root mail 63743972 Nov 14 16:40 /var/spool/mail/root
...........^
```

The ref count is 1, not 2 as I would expect!

And:

```
# find /var -inum 1284
/var/mail/root
```

That is, /var/mail/root is the only link pointing to inode 1284.

```
# find /var -samefile /var/mail/root
/var/mail/root
# find /var -samefile /var/spool/mail/root
/var/mail/root
```

It seems like /var/spool/mail/root is there, but is not.

Comment: What do you get from `ls -ld /var/mail /var/spool/mail`?

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you did quite some research there, didn't you? :D

The answer is much simpler tho. Yes, both entries point to the same inode. Thats because they are exactly the same file. Not even hardlinks. On most modern systems /var/spool/mail is a symlink to /var/mail.

Comment: Aaagh! How did I not think of it before?
Thank you.